# Index with text different from structure text

Tags: indexing, makeindex

How would to see in the index:

```
Borel, Émile, 6
   set, 7
```

I tried with

```
\index{Borel!set}
\index{Borel@Borel, Émile}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any wy to get it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\index{Borel!set}
\index{Borel@Borel, Émile} 
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've removed the `lualatex` tag as it's not specific to the TeX format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the top-level part exactly matches in both cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\index{Borel@Borel, Émile!set}
\index{Borel@Borel, Émile}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: image of index]

If you just have `\index{Borel!set}` then the parent is assumed to be just `\index{Borel}`, which isn't the same (from `makeindex`'s point of view) as `\index{Borel@Borel, Émile}`.

This need for an exact match is a requirement of `makeindex`. An alternative is to use `texindy` instead, which concatenates entries with the same sort value. That should work for the MWE in your question. (It might be a bit more complicated if you are using a custom `makeindex` style file in your actual document.)

Comment: Yes, my *unwritten* desire was not to write the whole name every time.  If no other solution comes up, I'll accept this one. Thank you.

Comment: @PeptideChain Unfortunately it has to exactly match, but an alternative approach would be to use the `glossaries` interface instead, where all the information only needs to be entered once and you can reference it by label. If you're interested I can add that as an alternative in my answer.

Comment: No, thank you. That would be a to big change for a small advantage.

Comment: @PeptideChain It's just occurred to me that there is another solution. You could use `texindy` instead of `makeindex`. That concatenates terms with the same sort value. It also supports UTF-8, which `makeindex` doesn't.